# Getting emails from apps-scripts-notifications@google.com and not sure what the issue is

Tags: google-apps-script

For the last week, I've been getting error messages from apps-scripts-notifications google.com but have not been able to figure the problem out or stop the emails. The click here link gives me a Forbidden 403 error. Anyone know what I can do to stop getting these emails? Thanks!

I initially asked this in Gmail Help Forum, but someone pointed me here.

This is what it looks like...
[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VUzG.png)

Comment: Can you share with us some code, e-mail you've got ?
D you have some trigger who's running which generate those e-mail ?

Comment: Do you have any scripts that you are using- perhaps they are failing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A Good question includes some code, and the line of code or general section of code that creates the error.  If this is a bug, then you will need to describe what situation reproduces the error, so that someone else can reproduce the error.  Because this is an Apps Script related issue, you might consider the [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: Completely forgot to attach that. Probably would be beneficial right? Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Goobric webApp has a time-based trigger that is sending that out. Its looking for authorization. If you type `type:script` into your google drive search it will show all scripts that are not bound to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Oooh, I think it was the Doctopus add-on for Google Sheets! Thanks! That type: script is a helpful tool! I forgot I revoked access on everything on my account after that Fake Google phishing scam last week...that's probably what started this.